# Web Page Crashes when Attempting to Print on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing

I am having an issue with both Google Chrome and Google Chrome Canary concerning printing. Every time I try to print a page, the web page crashes and I get the following error message:

[image: Aw, Snap!]

This has been happening consistently. How can I resolve the issue and get printing working again? I am using Google Chrome 44.

Comment: Did you try the "suggestions"?

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried recreating my user account, but that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the issue with web pages crashing when you try to print them in Google Chrome can be resolved by deleting Chrome's app data, which is located at `%localappdata%\Google`. After you delete Chrome's app data, launch Chrome, and it will appear as if you are launching it for the first time. Sign in to your Google account, and all of your plugins, history, bookmarks, etc. will be synced to your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Windows 7.

1. Close Chrome.
2. Use Windows Explorer (file explorer).
3. Go to Local Disk then `\Users\%Local User%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\` and then delete "Local State" file.
4. Open Chrome again.

Comment: Worked on Windows 10 too. Thanks!